# Can Thermomix(-style) appliances knead dough well?

Tags: equipment, pizza, kneading

I make italian-style pizza, by kneading the dough in a bread machine. The machine does a very good job (it works it for around 45 minutes), much better than I could do with my hands, and using a pizza stone oven, I can make a pizza that is very close to a traditional one.

Now, I was evaluating the purchase of a Thermomix-style appliance, so I was wondering - can such machines knead dough well?

(Note that I searched on the internet, but the most common type of home-made pizza is the thick one; I'm interested instead in the results for the traditional italian one - a few mm thick)

Comment: A dough hook in a machine can do a very good job of kneading (e.g. in my Kenwood - though I make pizza dough in the breadmaker because of the controlled proving temperature). You may have to optimise your recipe but I believe your question can be treated as a more general "can a thermomix knead dough well?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

German article about different kneading appliances: https://www.ploetzblog.de/2015/05/13/von-klebern-krume-und-knetern-sechs-knetmaschinen-im-praxistest/

In short: Thermomix is okay but leads to a warmer dough than others because of the motor being placed right below the bowl.

Others knead from above, so the dough stays cooler. Cooler dough means more time to proof, means more taste in your bread.

If you want your appliance mainly for kneading, there are better alternatives. He recommends the Kenwood Major or Kenwood Cooking Chef. The Cooking Chef has the advantage of a heating element (like the Thermomix), which is useful for special baking stuff like a "Malzstück" (malt-piece?, introduces a malty taste and needs cooking for longer time on a precise temperature).